# Door trim different depth on walls

Tags: doors, installation, trim, interior

Looking for a solution to trimming a door and struggling to do it the best way. Left side of door will fit normal casing size; however, the right side is 1.75" of difference in depth.

Since it's an already finished master bathroom, I've considered doing a barn door - I just prefer an actual door due to privacy. Here's a pic of depth difference:

[image: Picture of depth difference]

Comment: Please add a picture from further away, showing the difference between left and right sides and surrounding conditions.

Comment: From your description it sounds like the walls on the two sides of the door are in different planes.  The header in your picture is flush with the left wall but not the right, right?   If that is the case you cannot create a completely vanilla "normal casing".   *Somewhere* you have to transition to the new plane, unless you build out the entire left  wall to match!  Wider pictures and more description will help to understand this.

Comment: Yes. That's true @jay613. The plane is same left to right until it hits end of the door where it extends outward in the picture. I'll take another picture when I get home. So you're saying really the best bet is to extend trim out left to match? I hadn't seen anything where one side was a little extended around a corner despite the differing planes. Assumed it would look odd.